# CSS Selector Reference does not work even another selector is working well?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to code a very simple HTML CSS file and here is my problem.

Here is my code

```
[https:// codepen.io/anhbui2904/pen/jOxeQgw][1]
```

My problem is, as you can see in this picture

Because of this code

```
.service-section .service-item{
flex: 0 0 33.33%;
max-width: 33.33%;
padding: 15px;
}
```

The pictures become 3 pictures per 1 line. As you can see in this picture

[image: picture 1]

But I use this code

```
.work-section .work-item {
flex: 0 0 33.33%;
max-width: 33.33%;
padding: 15px;
}
```

[image: Problem 1]

As you can see, seems this code does not work ? The photos are still in line ? I do not know why ? Could you please give me some advice for this problem ? Thank you very much for your time.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700&display=swap');
body{
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background-color: #f3f2f1;
}

body,
input,textarea,
button{
    font-family: 'Raleway', 'sans-serif';
    font-weight: 400;
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

.container{
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: auto;
}
.row{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.align-items-center{
    align-items: center;
}

.justify-content-between{
    justify-content: space-between;
}

@keyframes ani01{
    0%{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
.section-title{
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.section-title h1{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.section-title h1:before{
    content: '';
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -5px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #ff9800;
}

.btn-01{
    background-color: #ff9800;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    padding: 10px 35px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.btn-01:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #FF9800;
    color:#ff9800;
}

.btn-01:focus{
    outline: none;
}

/* preloader */

/*.preloader{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #111111;
    z-index: 1099;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.6 ease;
}*/

.preloader.loaded{
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -99;
}

.preloader.loader{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #FF9800;
    border-right: 2px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: ani01 2s linear infinite;
}


/*Header*/

.header{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    width: 99;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.header .fixed{
    background-color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
}

.header .brand-name{
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.header.brand-name a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.header .fixed .brand-name a{
    color: #0000;
}

.header .nav-toggle{
    width: 40px;
    height: 34px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    display: none;
}

.header .fixed .nav-toggle {
    border-color: #000;
}

.header .nav-toggle span{
    height: 1px;
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.header .nav-toggle span::before,
.header .nav-toggle span::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.header .fixed .nav-toggle span,
.header .fixed .nav-toggle:before,
.header .fixed .nav-toggle::after{
    background-color: #000000;
}

.header .nav-toggle span:before{
    transform: translate(-6px);
}

.header .nav-toggle span:after{
    transform: translate(6px);
}

.header .nav{
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.header.nav ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.header .nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.header .nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 25px 0;
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.header .fixed .nav ul li a{
    color: #000000;
}

.header .fixed .nav ul li a:hover,
.header .nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #FF9800;
}

/* Home Section */

.home-section{
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('./img/moviebg.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.home-section:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: -1;
}

.home-section .shape-01{
    position:absolute;
    height: 30px;
    width:30px;
    border: 2px solid #FF9800;
    right: 5%;
    top: 20%;
    animation: ani01 5s linear infinite;
}

.home-section .row{
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.home-section .home-content{
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.home-section.home-content h4{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
}

.home-section .home-content h2{
    font-size: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
}

.home-section .scroll-down{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    animation: scrollDown 2s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes scrollDown{
    0%,20%,50%,80%,100%{
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    40%{
        transform: translateY(-30px);
    }
    60%{
        transform: translateY(-15px);
    }
}

.home-section .scroll-down img{
    width: 25px;
    display: block;
    margin: 2px auto;
}

.about-section {
    padding: 80px 0 0;
}

.about-section .about-img{
    flex: 0 0 33.33%;
    max-width: 33.33%;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.about-section .about-img .img-box{
    position: relative;
}

.about-section .about-img .img-box .shape-02{
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #FF9800;
    left: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    animation: ani01 5s linear infinite;
}

.about-section .about-img .img-box img{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.about-section .about-content{
    flex: 0 0 66.66%;
    max-width: 66.66%;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.about-section .section-title{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 0;
}

.about-section .about-content p{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #555555;
    line-height: 26px;
    margin: 0;
}

.about-section .about-content .stats .stat-box{
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
    padding: 0 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.about-section.about-content.stats.stat-box h2{
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #000000;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
}


.about-section .about-content .stats .stat-box h5{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #555555;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.about-section .about-content .btn{
    margin-top: 30px;
}

/*Categories*/

.service-section {
    padding: 80px 0;
}

.service-section .service-item{
    flex: 0 0 33.33%;
    max-width: 33.33%;
    padding: 15px;
}

.service-section .service-item-inner{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.service-section .service-item-inner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.service-section .service-item-inner img{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    filter:grayscale(100%);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;    
}

.service-section .service-item-inner:hover img{
    filter:grayscale(0);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.service-section .service-item-inner .overlay{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.service-section .service-item-inner:hover .overlay{
    background-color: transparent;
}

.service-section .service-item-inner .overlay h3{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}


.service-section .service-item-inner .overlay:hover h4{
    transform: translateX(30px);
    opacity: 0;
}

/* Top-Rated*/

.work-section{
    padding: 80px 0 0;
}

.work-section .work-item {
    flex: 0 0 33.33%;
    max-width: 33.33%;
    padding: 15px;
}

.work-section .work-item-inner img{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.work-section .work-item-inner:hover img{
    filter: grayscale(100);
    transform: scale(1);
}

.work-section .work-item-inner{
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.work-section .work-item-inner .overlay{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    opacity: 0;
}

.work-section .work-item-inner:hover .overlay{
    opacity: 1;
}

.work-section .work-item-inner:hover .overlay h4{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    transform: translateX(30px);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;;
}

.work-section .work-item-inner:hover .overlay h4{
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<body>

    <!--preloader-->
    <div class="preloader">
        <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>

    <!--preloader ends-->

    <!--Head section starts-->

    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="brand-name">
                    <a href="index.html">Movie Mania</a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-toggle">
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <nav class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#categories">Categories</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#top">Top-Rated</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

<!-- Header end -->

<!-- Home Section starts -->
<section class="home-section" id="home">

    <div class="shape-01">

    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="home-content">
                <h4>Download your favourite movie in just a click</h4>
                <h2>Welcome to Movie Mania</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Scroll Down-->
        <a href="#about" class="scroll-down">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/vHVsxYMk/arrow-down.png" alt="scroll down">
        </a>

    </div>

</section>

<!-- Home section end -->

<!-- About section start -->
<section class="about-section" id="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="about-img">
                <div class="img-box">
                    <div class="shape-02"></div>
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/76tk0b58/about.jpg" width = "30" height = "auto" alt="About US">
                </div>
            </div>            
        
          <div class="about-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="section-title">
                    <h1>About Us</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
            <div class="stats">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="stat-box">
                        <h2>150K+</h2>
                        <h5>Daily Downloads</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat-box">
                        <h2>2500+</h2>
                        <h5>Movies Available</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat-box">
                        <h2>1M+</h2>
                        <h5>Happy Clients</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Contact Button-->
            <a href="#contact" class="btn btn-01">Contact Us</a>
        </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!--About us ends -->

<!--Categories section start-->
<section class="service-section" id="categories">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="section-title">
                <h1>Categories</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <!--categories start-->
            <div class="service-item">
                <div class="service-item-inner">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/YShKkMXd/1.jpg" alt="category 1" width = "300" height = "auto">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h3>Ha Noi</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="service-item">
                <div class="service-item-inner">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/1z2x322s/2.jpg" alt="category 2" width = "300" height = "auto">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h3>Hai Phong</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="service-item">
                <div class="service-item-inner">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/BQBGBhLB/3.jpg" alt="category 3" width = "300" height = "auto">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h3>Nam Dinh</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="service-item">
                <div class="service-item-inner">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/XY2STpgZ/4.jpg" alt="category 4" width = "300" height = "auto">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h3>Thanh Hoa</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="service-item">
                <div class="service-item-inner">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/28DDvp65/5.jpg" alt="category 5" width = "300" height = "auto">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h3>Vinh</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="service-item">
                <div class="service-item-inner">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/jSqYgzy0/6.jpg" alt="category 6" width = "300" height = "auto">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h3>Hue</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!--Category section ends-->

<!--Top rated section start-->
<section class="work-section" id="top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="section-title">
                <h1>Top-Rated Movies</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="work-item">
                <div class="work-item-inner">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/854hHgGV/1.jpg" width = "300" height = "auto" data-large="./img/works/large/1.png" alt="Movie 1">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h4>Paris</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="work-item">
                <div class="work-item-inner">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/jjz6DJk2/2.jpg" width = "300" height = "auto" data-large="./img/works/large/2.png" alt="Movie 1">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h4>Berlin</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="work-item">
                <div class="work-item-inner">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/sXsY7Dtc/3.jpg" width = "300" height = "auto" data-large="./img/works/large/3.jpg" alt="Movie 1">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h4>Vill</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="work-item">
                <div class="work-item-inner">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/PqGzfMy0/4.jpg" width = "300" height = "auto" data-large="./img/works/large/4.jpg" alt="Movie 1">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h4>Thuong Hai</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="work-item">
                <div class="work-item-inner">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/65mfgKvW/5.jpg" width = "300" height = "auto" data-large="./img/works/large/5.jpg" alt="Movie 1">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h4>Bac Kinh</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="work-item">
                <div class="work-item-inner">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/jSn4r1Hz/6.jpg" width = "300" height = "auto" data-large="./img/works/large/6.png" alt="Movie 1">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h4>Trung Khanh</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!--top rated end -->


<!--contact section start-->

<section class="contact-section" id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="img-box">
                <div class="section-title">
                    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>   
    </div>
    
<div class="row">
    <div class="contact-form">
        <form class="form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="left input-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name Here" class="input-control">
                </div>

                <div class="right input-group">
                    <label>Email or Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email or Phone Here" class="input-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="left input-group">
                    <label>Message</label>
                    <textarea class="input-control" placeholder="Your Message Here"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-01" id="button">Send Message</button>
            </div>

            <div id="dialog">
                I know you know this, but you are awesome. As we say au revoir to another #ResearchPride month, 
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="contact-info">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="info-item">
                <h5>Address</h5>
                <p>X5 T7 U8 USA</p>
            </div>

            <div class="info-item">
                <h5>Phone</h5>
                <p>090 8403 1789</p>
            </div>

            <div class="info-item">
                <h5>Email</h5>
                <p>maviemanie@mivie.com</p>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="social-links">
        <a href="#" title="facebook"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/6Q9JPCRx/facebook.png" width = "100" height = "auto" alt="facebook"></a>
        <a href="#" title="twitter"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/zBvmz50d/twitter.png" width = "100" height = "auto" alt="twitter"></a>
        <a href="#" title="linkedin"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/7Pc4LGvS/linkedin.png" width = "100" height = "auto" alt="linkedin"></a>
        <a href="#" title="instagram"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/rsdLJc4d/intagram.jpg" width = "200" height = "auto" alt="intagram"></a>
    </div>
</div>

</section>



<p class="copyright">&copy; 2022 Movie Mania</p>
<!--light box start-->
<div class="lightbox">
    <div class="img-box">
        <div class="lightbox-close">&times;</div>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/qML93zSm/2.png" width = "100" height = "auto" class="lightbox-img" alt="img1">
        <div class="lightbox-caption">
            <div class="lightbox-category">

            </div>
            <div class="lightbox-counter">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="lightbox-controls">
            <div class="prev">
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/W4XLct6F/previous.png" width = "100" height = "auto" alt="previous">
            </div>
            <div class="next">
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/QdZrp2dt/next.png" width = "100" height = "auto" alt="next">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--light box end -->


</body>
```

Comment: put an executable code in a snippet so we can clearly understand the issue and edit it for you.

Comment: You need to put all the "work-items" in one **class="row"** instead of each with a **class="row"** boss. Because their parent needs the CSS property of the row class.

Comment: @Mad7Dragon Thanks, I have been added the code to the snippet, please reference them

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700&display=swap');
body{
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background-color: #f3f2f1;
}

body,
input,textarea,
button{
    font-family: 'Raleway', 'sans-serif';
    font-weight: 400;
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

.container{
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: auto;
}
.row{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.align-items-center{
    align-items: center;
}

.justify-content-between{
    justify-content: space-between;
}

@keyframes ani01{
    0%{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
.section-title{
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.section-title h1{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.section-title h1:before{
    content: '';
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -5px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #ff9800;
}

.btn-01{
    background-color: #ff9800;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    padding: 10px 35px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.btn-01:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #FF9800;
    color:#ff9800;
}

.btn-01:focus{
    outline: none;
}

/* preloader */

/*.preloader{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #111111;
    z-index: 1099;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.6 ease;
}*/

.preloader.loaded{
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -99;
}

.preloader.loader{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #FF9800;
    border-right: 2px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: ani01 2s linear infinite;
}


/*Header*/

.header{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    width: 99;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.header .fixed{
    background-color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
}

.header .brand-name{
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.header.brand-name a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.header .fixed .brand-name a{
    color: #0000;
}

.header .nav-toggle{
    width: 40px;
    height: 34px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    display: none;
}

.header .fixed .nav-toggle {
    border-color: #000;
}

.header .nav-toggle span{
    height: 1px;
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.header .nav-toggle span::before,
.header .nav-toggle span::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.header .fixed .nav-toggle span,
.header .fixed .nav-toggle:before,
.header .fixed .nav-toggle::after{
    background-color: #000000;
}

.header .nav-toggle span:before{
    transform: translate(-6px);
}

.header .nav-toggle span:after{
    transform: translate(6px);
}

.header .nav{
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.header.nav ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.header .nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.header .nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 25px 0;
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.header .fixed .nav ul li a{
    color: #000000;
}

.header .fixed .nav ul li a:hover,
.header .nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #FF9800;
}

/* Home Section */

.home-section{
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('./img/moviebg.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.home-section:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: -1;
}

.home-section .shape-01{
    position:absolute;
    height: 30px;
    width:30px;
    border: 2px solid #FF9800;
    right: 5%;
    top: 20%;
    animation: ani01 5s linear infinite;
}

.home-section .row{
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.home-section .home-content{
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.home-section.home-content h4{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
}

.home-section .home-content h2{
    font-size: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
}

.home-section .scroll-down{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    animation: scrollDown 2s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes scrollDown{
    0%,20%,50%,80%,100%{
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    40%{
        transform: translateY(-30px);
    }
    60%{
        transform: translateY(-15px);
    }
}

.home-section .scroll-down img{
    width: 25px;
    display: block;
    margin: 2px auto;
}

.about-section {
    padding: 80px 0 0;
}

.about-section .about-img{
    flex: 0 0 33.33%;
    max-width: 33.33%;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.about-section .about-img .img-box{
    position: relative;
}

.about-section .about-img .img-box .shape-02{
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #FF9800;
    left: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    animation: ani01 5s linear infinite;
}

.about-section .about-img .img-box img{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.about-section .about-content{
    flex: 0 0 66.66%;
    max-width: 66.66%;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.about-section .section-title{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 0;
}

.about-section .about-content p{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #555555;
    line-height: 26px;
    margin: 0;
}

.about-section .about-content .stats .stat-box{
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
    padding: 0 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.about-section.about-content.stats.stat-box h2{
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #000000;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
}


.about-section .about-content .stats .stat-box h5{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #555555;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.about-section .about-content .btn{
    margin-top: 30px;
}

/*Categories*/

.service-section {
    padding: 80px 0;
}

.service-section .service-item{
    flex: 0 0 33.33%;
    max-width: 33.33%;
    padding: 15px;
}

.service-section .service-item-inner{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.service-section .service-item-inner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.service-section .service-item-inner img{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    filter:grayscale(100%);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;    
}

.service-section .service-item-inner:hover img{
    filter:grayscale(0);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.service-section .service-item-inner .overlay{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.service-section .service-item-inner:hover .overlay{
    background-color: transparent;
}

.service-section .service-item-inner .overlay h3{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}


.service-section .service-item-inner .overlay:hover h4{
    transform: translateX(30px);
    opacity: 0;
}

/* Top-Rated*/

.work-section{
    padding: 80px 0 0;
}

.work-section .work-item {
    flex: 0 0 33.33%;
    max-width: 33.33%;
    padding: 15px;
}

.work-section .work-item-inner img{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.work-section .work-item-inner:hover img{
    filter: grayscale(100);
    transform: scale(1);
}

.work-section .work-item-inner{
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.work-section .work-item-inner .overlay{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    opacity: 0;
}

.work-section .work-item-inner:hover .overlay{
    opacity: 1;
}

.work-section .work-item-inner:hover .overlay h4{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    transform: translateX(30px);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;;
}

.work-section .work-item-inner:hover .overlay h4{
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<body>

    <!--preloader-->
    <div class="preloader">
        <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>

    <!--preloader ends-->

    <!--Head section starts-->

    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="brand-name">
                    <a href="index.html">Movie Mania</a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-toggle">
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <nav class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#categories">Categories</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#top">Top-Rated</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

<!-- Header end -->

<!-- Home Section starts -->
<section class="home-section" id="home">

    <div class="shape-01">

    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="home-content">
                <h4>Download your favourite movie in just a click</h4>
                <h2>Welcome to Movie Mania</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Scroll Down-->
        <a href="#about" class="scroll-down">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/vHVsxYMk/arrow-down.png" alt="scroll down">
        </a>

    </div>

</section>

<!-- Home section end -->

<!-- About section start -->
<section class="about-section" id="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="about-img">
                <div class="img-box">
                    <div class="shape-02"></div>
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/76tk0b58/about.jpg" width = "30" height = "auto" alt="About US">
                </div>
            </div>            
        
          <div class="about-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="section-title">
                    <h1>About Us</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
            <div class="stats">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="stat-box">
                        <h2>150K+</h2>
                        <h5>Daily Downloads</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat-box">
                        <h2>2500+</h2>
                        <h5>Movies Available</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat-box">
                        <h2>1M+</h2>
                        <h5>Happy Clients</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Contact Button-->
            <a href="#contact" class="btn btn-01">Contact Us</a>
        </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!--About us ends -->

<!--Categories section start-->
<section class="service-section" id="categories">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="section-title">
            <h1>Categories</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <!--categories start-->
        <div class="service-item">
            <div class="service-item-inner">
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/YShKkMXd/1.jpg" alt="category 1" width = "300" height = "auto">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <h3>Ha Noi</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="service-item">
            <div class="service-item-inner">
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/1z2x322s/2.jpg" alt="category 2" width = "300" height = "auto">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <h3>Hai Phong</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="service-item">
            <div class="service-item-inner">
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/BQBGBhLB/3.jpg" alt="category 3" width = "300" height = "auto">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <h3>Nam Dinh</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="service-item">
            <div class="service-item-inner">
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/XY2STpgZ/4.jpg" alt="category 4" width = "300" height = "auto">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <h3>Thanh Hoa</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="service-item">
            <div class="service-item-inner">
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/28DDvp65/5.jpg" alt="category 5" width = "300" height = "auto">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <h3>Vinh</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

         <div class="service-item">
            <div class="service-item-inner">
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/jSqYgzy0/6.jpg" alt="category 6" width = "300" height = "auto">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <h3>Hue</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
<!--Category section ends-->

<!--Top rated section start-->
<section class="work-section" id="top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="section-title">
                <h1>Top-Rated Movies</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="work-item">
                <div class="work-item-inner">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/854hHgGV/1.jpg" width = "300" height = "auto" data-large="./img/works/large/1.png" alt="Movie 1">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h4>Paris</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="work-item">
                <div class="work-item-inner">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/jjz6DJk2/2.jpg" width = "300" height = "auto" data-large="./img/works/large/2.png" alt="Movie 1">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h4>Berlin</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="work-item">
                <div class="work-item-inner">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/sXsY7Dtc/3.jpg" width = "300" height = "auto" data-large="./img/works/large/3.jpg" alt="Movie 1">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h4>Vill</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="work-item">
                <div class="work-item-inner">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/PqGzfMy0/4.jpg" width = "300" height = "auto" data-large="./img/works/large/4.jpg" alt="Movie 1">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h4>Thuong Hai</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="work-item">
                <div class="work-item-inner">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/65mfgKvW/5.jpg" width = "300" height = "auto" data-large="./img/works/large/5.jpg" alt="Movie 1">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h4>Bac Kinh</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="work-item">
                <div class="work-item-inner">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/jSn4r1Hz/6.jpg" width = "300" height = "auto" data-large="./img/works/large/6.png" alt="Movie 1">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h4>Trung Khanh</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!--top rated end -->


<!--contact section start-->

<section class="contact-section" id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="img-box">
                <div class="section-title">
                    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>   
    </div>
    
<div class="row">
    <div class="contact-form">
        <form class="form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="left input-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name Here" class="input-control">
                </div>

                <div class="right input-group">
                    <label>Email or Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email or Phone Here" class="input-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="left input-group">
                    <label>Message</label>
                    <textarea class="input-control" placeholder="Your Message Here"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-01" id="button">Send Message</button>
            </div>

            <div id="dialog">
                I know you know this, but you are awesome. As we say au revoir to another #ResearchPride month, 
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="contact-info">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="info-item">
                <h5>Address</h5>
                <p>X5 T7 U8 USA</p>
            </div>

            <div class="info-item">
                <h5>Phone</h5>
                <p>090 8403 1789</p>
            </div>

            <div class="info-item">
                <h5>Email</h5>
                <p>maviemanie@mivie.com</p>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="social-links">
        <a href="#" title="facebook"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/6Q9JPCRx/facebook.png" width = "100" height = "auto" alt="facebook"></a>
        <a href="#" title="twitter"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/zBvmz50d/twitter.png" width = "100" height = "auto" alt="twitter"></a>
        <a href="#" title="linkedin"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/7Pc4LGvS/linkedin.png" width = "100" height = "auto" alt="linkedin"></a>
        <a href="#" title="instagram"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/rsdLJc4d/intagram.jpg" width = "200" height = "auto" alt="intagram"></a>
    </div>
</div>

</section>



<p class="copyright">&copy; 2022 Movie Mania</p>
<!--light box start-->
<div class="lightbox">
    <div class="img-box">
        <div class="lightbox-close">&times;</div>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/qML93zSm/2.png" width = "100" height = "auto" class="lightbox-img" alt="img1">
        <div class="lightbox-caption">
            <div class="lightbox-category">

            </div>
            <div class="lightbox-counter">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="lightbox-controls">
            <div class="prev">
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/W4XLct6F/previous.png" width = "100" height = "auto" alt="previous">
            </div>
            <div class="next">
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/QdZrp2dt/next.png" width = "100" height = "auto" alt="next">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--light box end -->


</body>
```